# Is "I've been to the country about which we had talked last month" grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I have learned that prepositions can be used in relative clauses. 
For example:

> The man **to whom** my mother is talking is my teacher

But this sentence

> I've been to the country about which we had talked last month

does not sound right to natives. I wonder if this is grammatically wrong and the reason why.

Comment: Who told you that "natives" think differently about your two examples? They both pointlessly / awkwardly include exactly the same kind of unnecessary ***wh-*** pronoun, as opposed to *The man my mother is talking **to** is my teacher, I've been to the country we talked **about** last month.* Note that you *don't* want Past Perfect ***had*** in that second utterance. Other than that, it's just that native speakers don't usually like unnecessary complexity, but *grammatically*, all alternatives are fine.

Comment: "This is the type of errant pedantry up with which I will not put." (Quote ascribed, [probably apocryphally](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/11/14/churchill-on-prepositions/), to Winston Churchill)

Comment: Thank you! But may I ask why past perfect "had" shouldn't be there?

Comment: You could say "I went to the country about which we had talked (_or_ that we had talked about) the previous month."